# Swaping div @media screen

Tags: html, css

Here left DIV is stretchable and right DIV is fixed. The code is working as expected. The only problem is when screen size is below 480px the right DIV goes up and left div goes down. But I wish just the reverse.

See here  http://jsfiddle.net/ask2asim/wcjo4zLs/

The HTML:

```
<div class="right"></div> 
<div class="left"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #f0f
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 2px dashed #00f
}


@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .left {
    width: 100%;
}

.right {
    width: 100%;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just swap classes in your markup, since there are siblings that won't make any difference and it will work the way you want. What you are trying to do is not possible now since the [General sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) can not be applied that way.

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
>   parent.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
.left, .right{display: inline-block; min-height: 50px}
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc(100% - 220px); /*This is the parent width - (.right width + 10x2 marginRight bellow)*/
    border: 2px dashed #f0f;
    margin-right: 10px
}

.right {
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px dashed #00f
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    
    .left, .right {width: 100%}

}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

an alternative would be `list` element and `direction: ltr/rtl`

Comment: I am not expert in CSS, Could you please see here http://jsfiddle.net/ask2asim/wcjo4zLs/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `float:left`

```
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #f0f;
    float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rules in media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 

    .left {
        width: 100%; float: left;
    }

    .right {      
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;  width: 100%;        
    }

}
```

Comment: can u pls share your code in jsfiddle, so that we can see actual problem